# automatic water stop valve?

Tags: water, leak, protection

I am looking for a simple mechanical device that I can install in the supply line for the fridge-water-filter and that will turn of the water if it ever runs for more than a minute. (Most fridges turn off the water themselves after about a minute, so if the water runs longer, there is a leak.)

I am assuming a device like this would be simple to build, yet I have been unable to find one for purchase. Does something like that exist?

I would prefer a mechanical solution, but an electronic one would work too. However, I don't want the system to rely on some form of humidity detection, as that does not reliably work with a fridge (I just had a fridge completely fill with water before it started leaking.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, and most reliable, method (I think :-) ) is to put a drain tray under the frig, with a float switch tied to an electronic valve. If the tray fills, the switch cuts off the inlet valve.   BTW - whether or not your frig has an internal timeout, that timeout won't prevent a flood, since (1) the leak could be ahead of the timeout valve and (2) once the down-time counter is done, the frig would start up again anyway.

That said, may I suggest that you're in a "once bitten; twice shy" scenario?  Unless you Google your particular model and find many complaints of leak failures, it's highly unlikely this will happen again in your lifetime.